# in Scala, execute a block and ignore but log exceptions

Tags: scala

Apache has `IOUtils.closeQuietly(Closeable)`. In Scala, I'd like to generalize this: execute a block and ingore exceptions, while at the same time logging them. Something like this:

```
import LogUtils._

object Playground extends App {
  implicit val logger_ = LoggerFactory.getLogger(getClass)
  silentLog {
    println("block")
    throw new Exception("an exception")
  }
  println("end")
}


import org.slf4j.{Logger, LoggerFactory}
import scala.util.control.NonFatal

object LogUtils {
  def silentLog[U](f: => U)(implicit log: Logger) {
    try f
    catch {
      case NonFatal(e) => log.error(null, e)
    }
  }
}
```

Is this already implemented in some common library?

Comment: I guess not, as generally not a good practice

Answer (score 0):

`Try[T]` does this to some extent but does not log the exception. `Try` does `try .. catch ...` inside

```
def LoggingTry[T](f: => T)(implicit logger: Logger): Try[T] = Try(f()).recoverWith {
  case th =>
    logger.log(th)
    Try { throw th }
}
```

Use `getOrElse(())` if you want to get value in case of success and default value (Unit) in case of failure

Comment: I don't think this is what *OP* wants. Ultimately, you are throwing again and wrapping it into `Try` that has to be handled at some point, preferably pattern matched or flatmaped.

Comment: @sebszyller if you don't want pattern matching do `getOrElse`

Comment: @sebszyller even in case of `silentLog` the return type would be `Any` and so you got to pattern match some time or other

Comment: that's true. It should be implemented with some type-safety in mind, though. *OP's* solution does not achieve this neither does `getOrElse()` where you have `someValue` in case of success or default `Unit`. Maybe making it an `Option` and `folding` it? It would ensure the type consistency; just food for thought.

Comment: @sebszyller `Try` is better than `Option`. Try is more informative because it tells why the computation failed. even in case of `option` you got to pattern match.  What do you mean by `folding` how does it solve the problem

Comment: you can `fold` the option to provide it with default value but unlike `getOrElse` it is type safe. I wouldn't argue that `Try` is inherently better, merely different.

Comment: the intended return of `silentLog` is Unit. There is no result to process. think of the provided example `IOUtils.closeQuietly(Closeable)`.

Comment: @DavidPortabella Nothing of that sought is available in scala but you could use Try to achieve some of it as mentioned above

Comment: thanks Pamu, but I don't understand why I would use `Try`. The `silentLog` method I've provided in the question already does the job. I was only asking if that was already implemented in some library.

Comment: @DavidPortabella Yes `silentLog` does the job. but `Try[T]` is already available in Scala to protect code from exceptions internally `Try` does try catch.